# mat-options only appearing on second click of dropdown or if the window is resized

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

This is what my html looks like:

```
<mat-form-field class="w-10 pad-r5">
<input #solutionInputAuto
    #solutionTrigger="matAutocompleteTrigger"
    (click)="openPanel($event, solutionTrigger, solutionsControl, solutionInputAuto)"
    (blur)="solutionChange()"
    [(ngModel)]="messagesService.messagesRequest.Solution"                
    [formControl]="solutionsControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="solutionAuto"
    type="text"
    placeholder="{{messagesService.solutionsPlaceholder}}"
    aria-label="Solution"
    matInput>
<mat-autocomplete #solutionAuto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of matAutoSolutions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

If the dropdown is clicked, nothing appears. I have to click off and then click back to the dropdown. Or if I open the dropdown and then resize the window, the items appear. The dropdown opens, but for reason, they're not draw properly.

This is what openPanel looks like:

```
openPanel(evt: any, trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger, control: FormControl, input: any): void {
  evt?.stopPropagation();
  control?.reset();
  trigger?.openPanel();
  input?.nativeElement?.focus();
}
```

Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

Comment: could you provide a minimal working stackblitz for quick debugging!